# How can I load a local config.env in an bash-file when executed remotely?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, terminal, .env

I have a local `config.env` which is called in a local `local.sh`. However, when I use a SSH connection to execute that file on a remote server it's not working anymore.

---

**Example**

`config.env`

```
HELLO="world"
```

`local.sh`

```
. config.env
printf "Test: %s\n" "$HELLO" # working
```

---

When executing `ssh -T user@server 'bash -s' < ./local.sh` it's not working anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
ssh -T user@server 'bash -s' < <(cat config.env local_as_remote.sh)
```

and remove `. config.env` line from local_as_remote.sh

Comment: Sadly I get an error on this

`syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: Sorry, a typo in my answer. Updated now.

Comment: Great thats working. I always wonder how to know this special quotations like "< <(...)"... I tried everything before but no chance to guess that. 

Do you think this approach right know is some kind of "best practice" or is there another common way without `config.env`?

Comment: Given your needs, I'd say this is "normal practice".